# Deleting Github Commits

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

Is there anyway I can get rid of this commits and let the last one stay there?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? One point of version control is to allow you to go back if e.g. you realise you've made a mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `master` branch you could do:

```sh
git reset --hard \<commit-hash>

git push -f origin master
```

`commit-hash` would be the last commit in your case.

**CAUTION**: If your remote repo `master` is used by multiple people and frequently has changes Pushed to it, you should first consult with your teamates before doing a `reset`.

Also if you cannot do the above, you can look at [Undo published commits with new commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit/4114122)

Comment: **WARNING**: This destroys all commits after the specified one. If you instead want to collapse them into a single commit, consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git